# Maven build doesn't include hibernate cfg.xml or hbm.xml files

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I'm building and executable-jar but the jar doesn't include the cfg or hbm hibernate files. My pom file contains the following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          <mainClass>com.myCompany.myProject.myMainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    </build>
```

I'm using the following to build it:

> mvn clean package shade:shade

I get errors that my hibernate cfg and hbm files cannot be found.

Any ideas? I've burned many BTUs on this already. Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, Maven won't generate those files for you. [This](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/quick-start-maven-hibernate-mysql-example/) article might help you out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

put those files in `src/main/resources` maven takes everything in package from `resources`

Comment: does that mean any and all reference to those file need to be updated to point to src/main/resources too? Those files are currently in several packages.

Comment: no, when it packs it to jar it puts them into the same path same classpath, so for example if you have file at `com.abc.def` put in `src/main/java/com/abc/def` put it at same location in `src/main/resources/com/abc/def`, nothing needs to be changed

Comment: Ah! I see said the blind man, as he picked up his hammer and saw. Thanks for the quick response ... all working now.

Answer (score 11):

```
<build>
   <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>  
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

this solved my problem